# Modeling simple laser induced population transfer via adiabatic passage in python

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics

I'm trying to model adiabatic passage between two levels in a three-level atom interacting with two laser fields using Scipy and Numpy.[image: three-level atom].

I'm not sure if my model is wrong due to my incorrectly formulating the equations in python or the Scipy ODE solver picking up errors.

To get the coefficients of each of the three states I use

$$
i\frac{d}{dt}\left( \begin{array}{c}
c_1 \\
c_2 \\
c_3  \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \Omega_1(t) & 0 \\
\Omega_1(t) & 0 & \Omega_2(t) \\
0 & \Omega_2(t) & 0 \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c}
c_1 \\
c_2 \\
c_3  \end{array}\right)
$$

Where $\Omega_{1,2}(t)$ give the (slow) time dependence of the amplitudes of the electric fields generated by the two laser beams. The initial conditions are $c_1(-\infty) = 1, c_2(-\infty) = c_3(-\infty) = 0 $.

I assume the Gaussian forms of $\Omega_{1,2}(t)$:

$$
\Omega_{1}(t) = exp(-(t-\tau)^2/T^2)
$$

and

$$
\Omega_{2}(t) = exp(-(t+\tau)^2/T^2)
$$

where $\tau$ is the delay time such that a positive value of $\tau$ means that field 2 is switched on before field 1. $T$ sets the duration of the pulses.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import exp
from collections import defaultdict
import pylab as p

tau = 2
T = 1

def omega1(t,tau=tau,T=T):
    return exp(-(t - tau)**2/T**2)

def omega2(t,tau=tau,T=T):
    return exp(-(t + tau)**2/T**2)

def g(y, t,tau=tau,T=T):
    c1_i = y[0]
    c2_i = y[1]
    c3_i = y[2]

    g1 = omega1(t, tau, T)*c2_i
    g2 = omega1(t, tau, T)*c1_i + omega2(t)*c3_i
    g3 = omega2(t, tau, T)*c2_i
    return [g1, g2, g3]

# initial conditions
c1_0 = 1
c2_0 = 0
c3_0 = 0

y0 = [c1_0, c2_0, c3_0]

step_size = 1000
t_max = 10.
t_min = 0.
delta_t = (t_max - t_min)/step_size

t = np.linspace(t_max, t_min, step_size) # time grid
soln = odeint(g, y0, t)
c1 = soln[:, 0]
c2 = soln[:, 1]
c3 = soln[:, 2] 

# plot results
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, np.abs(c1), label='c1')
plt.plot(t, np.abs(c2), label='c2')
plt.plot(t, np.abs(c3), label='c3')

plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('energy level population')
plt.title('initial attempt')
plt.legend(loc=0)
```

[image: initial result]

The result seems wrong since it shows the coefficients having values above one. Furthermore, I can't seem to find values of $\tau$ and $T$ that yield a non-zero final $c_3$ value.

One issue that might be contributing is that currently my answer doesn't include the multiplication by $i$. I'm not sure how to include that in my python equations.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about debugging a code than the physics behind the model. Perhaps [scicomp.se] might be better suited for this question.

Comment: Also, [Python supports complex numbers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html), not sure how/why you missed that one.